# UBI is "pausing" before boot

Tags: ubifs

I have installed a ubifs image on my embedded board, but at boot time, when I turn on my board, the boot is paused for a few seconds (approx. 10 seconds) with this output:

```
Booting from nand ...

NAND read: device 0 offset 0x280000, size 0x800000
 8388608 bytes read: OK
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
Booting from nand with DTS...
UBI: attaching mtd1 to ubi0
UBI: scanning is finished
UBI: attached mtd1 (name "mtd=4", size 1013 MiB) to ubi0
UBI: PEB size: 131072 bytes (128 KiB), LEB size: 129024 bytes
UBI: min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048/2048, sub-page size 512
UBI: VID header offset: 512 (aligned 512), data offset: 2048
UBI: good PEBs: 8108, bad PEBs: 0, corrupted PEBs: 0
UBI: user volume: 1, internal volumes: 1, max. volumes count: 128
UBI: max/mean erase counter: 1/0, WL threshold: 4096, image sequence number: 1663921903
UBI: available PEBs: 6533, total reserved PEBs: 1575, PEBs reserved for bad PEB handling: 160
```

I made the ubi image using the following commands:

```
sudo mkfs.ubifs -v -m 2048 -e 129024 -c 1675 -r $PWD/$1 -o rootfs.img
sudo ubinize -o rootfs.ubi -p 131072  -m 2048 -s 512 -O 512 ubi.ini
```

where, of course, $1 is the rootfs dir of the file system. And the ubi.ini file content is this:

```
[rootfs]
mode=ubi
image=rootfs.img
vol_id=4
vol_type=static
vol_name=rootfs
vol_alignment=1
```

Perhaps there is something wrong in my configuration file ? How can I avoid UBI pausing the boot ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved changing line:

```
vol_type=static
```

to

```
vol_type=dynamic
```

From here: http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/ubi.html#L_dyn_faster